# проблема с Enum в random не коректно отображается сытость кота

Tags: c#

при воспроизведение 24 строки где генерируется рандомом что будет кушать кот из енама там прописан для каждого продукта свой уровень сытости но при воспроизвидению консолью он рандомно закидывает туда сытость то есть не присвоеный енаму
хотя если кот пьет воду то присвоеная сытость показывается правильно но остальное рандомно

```
 namespace ex14;
    
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int currentSatietyLevel = random.Next(1, 150);
            int desiretSatietyLevel = random.Next(1, 150);
            Console.WriteLine($"Current satiety level  {currentSatietyLevel}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Desired satiety level  {desiretSatietyLevel} ");
            if (currentSatietyLevel < desiretSatietyLevel)
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Hey don't forget to feed your cat \n" +
                                      "What will you feed your cat\n" + "Milk\n" + "Water\n" + "Beef\n" + "Chiken\n" +
                                      "Kitekat\n");
                    Food[] arrayfood = { Food.Milk, Food.Water, Food.Beef, Food.Chiken, Food.Kitekat };
                    int a = random.Next(0, 5);
                    int b = Convert.ToInt32(arrayfood[a]);
                    currentSatietyLevel = currentSatietyLevel + (Convert.ToInt32(b));
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate " +
                                      (arrayfood[
                                          random.Next(
                                              5)])); /*Здесь  выдает  мне  индекс  массива,  я хочу  еду.  которая  под  этим  индексом. */
                    Console.WriteLine("satiety level  = {0}", currentSatietyLevel);
                } while (currentSatietyLevel < desiretSatietyLevel);
    
                Console.WriteLine("The cat overate");
            }
            else if (currentSatietyLevel == desiretSatietyLevel)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Сat ate");
            }
            else if (currentSatietyLevel > desiretSatietyLevel)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("It's time for the cat to go on a diet");
            }
        }
    
        static void Operation(Food Oper)
        {
            Food kitekat = Food.Kitekat;
            Food water = Food.Water;
            Food milk = Food.Milk;
            Food beef = Food.Beef;
            Food chiken = Food.Chiken;
            switch (Oper)
            {
                case Food.Kitekat:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate  kitekat, satiety level =  {0} ", (int)kitekat);
                    break;
                case Food.Water:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat drank water satiety level = {0}", (int)water);
                    break;
                case Food.Milk:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat drank  milk, satiety level = {0}", (int)milk);
                    break;
                case Food.Beef:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate Beef, satiety level = {0}", (int)beef);
                    break;
                case Food.Chiken:
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat ate chiken , satiety level = {0}", (int)chiken);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong food");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
 

      public enum Food
    {
        Milk = 20,
        Water = 30,
        Beef = 100, 
        Chiken = 70, 
        Kitekat = 50, 
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте данные изменения так как в первом случае вы заново получаете индекс массива поэтому название пищи одно, а сытность другая.
Так же ваш массив состоит из 5 элементов тоесть Рандом используйте с 0 - 4.

```
Console.WriteLine("Cat ate " +(arrayfood[random.Next(5)]));//Здесь вы заново определяете какую еду съест кот. Необходимо изменить на:
Console.WriteLine("Cat ate " +(arrayfood[a]));

int a = random.Next(0, 5);//так же изменить на:
int a = random.Next(0,4)//так как ваш массив с едой начинается с индекса 0 и заканчивается 4
```

Comment: Все равно такая же проблема 
Desired satiety level  132
Hey don't forget to feed your cat
What will you feed your cat
Milk
Water
Beef
Chiken
Kitekat

Cat ate Water
satiety level  = 135
The cat overate
Хотя согласна enum

Comment: Я обновил код попробуйте сейчас

Comment: У меня всё работает, обновите страницу и заново проверьте всё ли вы изменили.

Comment: в методе `random.Next(0, 5)` верхний предел не возвращается, так что возможные значения 0,1,2,3,4 и менять рандом не нужно

Comment: всем спасибо решил проблему